# Unable to Give Dynamic Name in .write function

Tags: python, xml, tkinter

I am using ttinker to give path for exporting a file,then trying to given a dynamic name to the output file
the MRBTS is a changing varible

Issue is sometimes i am able to save the file in the given directory,but the name of the file automatically changes to the directory name
i think there is an issue either in the filedialog.askdirectory() which is have used can some one guide ?

```
Regen.configure(bg="grey")
Regen.geometry("300x300+500+200")
mylabel1=Label(text="VIL Regen Tool",fg="orange",bg="grey",font="Times 15 bold").pack()
mylabel1=Label(text="Developed by Sushanto Banerjee",fg="orange",bg="grey",font="Times 15 bold").place(x=10,y=100)

def xml_import():
    global xml_file
    xml_file=filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=[("XML files","*.xml")])
    label1=Label(text="XML Backup Imported").place(x=100,y=240)
def excel_import():
    global excel_file
    excel_file=filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files","*.xlsx")])
    label2=Label(text="IP Plan Imported").place(x=120,y=270)
def export():
    global export_dir
    export_dir=filedialog.askdirectory()
    a=filedialog.
    mess=messagebox.showinfo(title="XML Generated",message="XMl generated")
    command=Regen.destroy()
    
button=Button(text="Import XML Backup",width=30,command=xml_import).pack()
button=Button(text="Import Excel IP Plan",width=30,command=excel_import).pack()
button=Button(text="Generate",width=30,command=export).pack()

Regen.mainloop()



                mytree.write( export_dir + str(MRBTS) +'_IPV6.xml',encoding='UTF-8')
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `export_dir` is what you expect at the time of the writing? Have you verified that `export_dir + str(MRBTS)` is what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is right here:

`export_dir + str(MRBTS) +'_IPV6.xml'`

`askdirectory()` does not include the trailing slash. What you actually want is:

`f'{export_dir}\{MRBTS}_IPV6.xml'`

However, a cleaner method is illustrated below:

```
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog
from os import path

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.title("Test")
   

#with one function handling all the save logic
#~it becomes harder to make mistakes and easier to find them
def save_utf8(filename, data):
    folder   = filedialog.askdirectory()
    filepath = path.join(folder, filename)
    with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data.encode('utf-8'))

        
#represents some data that your app concocted
MRBTS   = 'blahblah'
xmldata = '<blah>BLAH</blah><blah>BLAH</blah><blah>BLAH</blah>'


#utilize the save function
save_utf8(f'{MRBTS}_IPV6.xml', xmldata)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks f'{export_dir}\{MRBTS}_IPV6.xml did the trick i used / (forward slash and it worked